# Завершение python скрипта по истечении времени

Tags: python, crontab

Я написал небольшой python скрипт который выгружает данные с API в многопоточном режиме и сохраняет их в базу данных. Через crontab поставил его на запуск раз в 5 минут, но столкнулся с такой проблемой что выполнение программы иногда не заканчивается и за пару дней работы такие "мертвые" процессы забивают всю память. Мне кажется что если будет вызываться `sys.exit()` через 10 минут работы это решит мою проблему, но как это сделать? Если сделать отдельный поток который мониторит время выполнения то  `sys.exit()` завершит только его. Может быть есть какие то способы ограничить время выполнения скрипта на уровне ОС?

Comment: Запустите через systemd timer и поставьте параметр watchdog. Cron это конечно круто, но таймеры функциональней

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать в тот же крон запихать скрипт, отслеживающий время с момента запуска пайтон скриптов.

Получить все запущенные python с временем запуска (грепать можно и не python а имя вашего скрипта)

> ps -eo pid,lstart,etime,args|grep python

потом вычленить излишне долго висящие и убить

Answer (score 0):

Использовал сигналы, основной код:

```
    try:
        with time_limit(10):
            main()
    except TimeoutException as e:
        log.warning("TIME LIMIT")
```

Создал класс ошибки нехватки времени и счетчик времени:

```
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager


class TimeoutException(Exception): pass


@contextmanager
def time_limit(seconds):
    def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutException("Timed out!")

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
    signal.alarm(seconds)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)
```

Comment: не люблю я аларм. да ещё в таком виде может выполнятся только один контекст менеджер